# Index.names is not assigned after using concat

Tags: python, pandas

After running the following code, `index.names` returns `[None]` but I'm expecting `['Server']`. Can you reproduce this? Is this expected behavior, if so why?

```
import pandas as pd
try:
  from io import StringIO
except ImportError:
  from StringIO import StringIO

data1 = "Cores\tServer\n20,000\tS000\n-20,000\tS003\n16,000\tS140\n2,000\tS148\n2,000\tS149\n"

data2 = "Cores\tServer\n20,000\tS103\n16,000\tS140\n2,000\tS148\n2,000\tS149\n4,000\tS150\n"

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), sep='\t', index_col=['Server'], decimal=',')
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data2), sep='\t', index_col=['Server'], decimal=',')

df1.rename(columns=lambda x: x + '_1', inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns=lambda x: x + '_2', inplace=True)

joined = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(joined)
print(joined.index.name)
print(joined.index.names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've got an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13475) - I think it likely is a bug, here is a workaround:

```
In [93]: df1.join(df2, how='outer')
Out[93]: 
        Cores_1  Cores_2
Server                  
S000       20.0      NaN
S003      -20.0      NaN
S103        NaN     20.0
S140       16.0     16.0
S148        2.0      2.0
S149        2.0      2.0
S150        NaN      4.0
```

Comment: It's actually not **my** issue. I did not create it. I just added a comment on the issue because it seems that I have the same problem.